# Websocket Connection is being refused on node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, ports

I am trying to learn WebRTC from tutorialspoint and making a video call demo app. I am using Windows pc and node.js static server. When I run static command from `cmd` in project root directory and navigate to `localhost:8080` I got this output in my browser console:

```
Websocket connection to ws://localhost:9090/ failed:Error in connection established: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The line which is causing error:

```
var Conn=new websocket('ws://localhost:9090');
```

Comment: Assuming you actually have network connectivity from the browser to the desired server (which should be the case if `localhost:9090` is correct), we will likely need to see your server code to have a better idea what's going on here.

Comment: I am using exact same code from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_video_demo.htm

Comment: Is port 9090 listening (check with `netstat`)? Could any firewall block your application?

Comment: I am not familiar with netstat so please tell me how to use it.

Comment: `netstat -a` in cmd. You should have an entry like this `TCP    127.0.0.1:9090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`. If  not, it means that you have a problem with your application.

Comment: There was no entry like that so after reading an article from internet I downloaded a program called portlistener and configured it to listen on port 9090 and after that when i ran my demo app i got a new error. : Websocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed :Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line

Comment: I don't think that it's a good solution. Your NodeJs application should provide you the websocket service. You should have a line like `var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9090});` on your NodeJs server, don't you?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you exactly mean

Answer (score 2):

Try Replacing localhost with the IP address of the machine on which the Node server is running.

Comment: I do not have an internet connection on my server so the ip address of my server will be 127.0.0.1 which is not working either

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue :

1. Ensure you've WebSockets(ws) library for Node.js and wscat utility installed.

   To install ws globally run `npm install ws -g` in the terminal.
    To install wscat globally  run `npm install wscat -g` in your terminal
2. Ensure socket is litening on the specified port

   In your case run `wscat -l 9090` to listen on port 9090.